# Use clang to extract documentation comments as XML

Tags: clang, libclang

I've seen [this](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Gribenko_CommentParsing.pdf) presentation from 2012 on `clang` features to handle `C++` documentation comments (eg. for `doxygen`). Slide `20` mentions a new feature to export comments as XML as being part of `libclang`.

I'd like to try that feature out. More specifically, I want to test producing an XML like shown on slide `31`.

But I don't know how. Which tool of `libclang` is this part of? Was the tool removed in the meantime? Or is this just an extra compiler flag?

Answer (score 0):

They might just be referring to…

    `CXString clang_FullComment_getAsXML( CXComment Comment)`

… which returns an XML document for the given comment. You still need to traverse the node trees yourself.

It would be spectacular to have an option for dropping an XML file containing the extracted documentation during a regular compile, but it doesn't seem to be in the cards.